# PHP5 how to add simplexml?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

When i check my **phpinfo** , it displays like below and i have to use  **simplexml**, but getting ;

> "Fatal error: Call to undefined function **simplexml_load_file()**
>   in..."

message.

> disable-xml' '--disable-simplexml' '--disable-dom' '--disable-libxml' '--disable-xmlreader' '--disable-xmlwriter' '--disable-debug'

How can i enable **simplexml** ?

Comment: Which PHP version you are using? check with `php -v` .

Comment: i have ,PHP 5.4.16

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Install:**

```
apt-get install php-xml
```

**Check:**

```
php -m | grep xml
```

**Restart:**

```
service php5-fpm restart
```

Comment: infact i already have this libray ,php -m | grep xml ->
libxml
xml
, dont need to install it but still getting "Fatal error: Call to undefined function simplexml_load_file() in...",  am i missing something?

Comment: can you share the result of `php -m` and `php -v`?

Comment: [PHP Modules]
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
gmp
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mhash
openssl
pcntl
pcre
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
standard
tokenizer
xml
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]

Comment: php -v
PHP 5.4.16 (cli)

Comment: for php5, use `sudo apt-get install php5.6-xml`

Answer (score 2):

Run this command in ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-xml
```

Answer (score 1):

You must recompile your php source code and enable all of the related XML plugin.

Like this:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php --enable-xml --enable-simplexm --enable-libxml  //and so on...
```